# CSS [attribute~=value] selector behaviour

Tags: css, css-selectors

This selector is used to select elements with an attribute value containing a given word.

For example `title~="image"` will match `title="image"` and `title="first image"`.

But it won't match `title="images"`, even though "images" contains "image".

Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [CSS Selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors):

> `[att~=val]`
>  Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, **one of which is exactly "val"**. If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.

If you want to match `title="images"`, you can use the [`[att*=val]` substring-matching selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) instead:

> `[att*=val]`
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

```css
[class*="foo"] {
  margin: 0;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foo">foo</figure>
<figure class="foo bar">foo bar</figure>
<figure class="bar foo">bar foo</figure>
<figure class="foos bar">foos bar</figure>
```